# protobuf-net Sub-message not read correctly

Tags: c#, exception, protobuf-net

I'm currently testing protobuf-net (latest version), but intermittently I'm getting "Sub-message not read correctly" exception while deserializing. So far there's no apparent pattern to reproduce this error, and the data is always the same.

I googled this error and so far people reported this error only when dealing with big data (>20MB), which I'm not doing.

Can anyone point out whether this is a bug (and if it is, any possible solution to fix/circumvent this?), or am I missing some steps? Below is the code I'm using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using ProtoBuf;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string message = "Cycle {0}: {1:N2} ms - avg: {2:N2} ms - min: {3:N2} - max: {4:N2}";
            const int loop = 1000;

            var counter = new Stopwatch();
            var average = 0d;
            var min = double.MaxValue;
            var max = double.MinValue;

            for (int i = 0;; i++)
            {
                var classThree = Create();

                counter.Reset();
                counter.Start();

                Parallel.For(0, loop, j =>
                {
                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        Serializer.Serialize(ms, classThree);
                        using (var ms2 = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray()))
                        {
                            var des = Serializer.Deserialize<ClassThree>(ms2);
                            var aaa = des;
                        }
                    }
                });

                counter.Stop();

                var elapsed = counter.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
                average += elapsed;
                min = Math.Min(min, elapsed);
                max = Math.Max(max, elapsed);
                var currentAverage = average / (i + 1);

                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine(message, i, elapsed, currentAverage, min, max);

                Thread.Sleep(0);
            }
        }

        private static ClassThree Create()
        {
            var classOne = new ClassSix()
            {
                // properties
                p_i1 = -123,
                p_i2 = 456,
                p_l1 = -456,
                p_l2 = 123,
                p_s = "str",
                p_f = 12.34f,
                p_d = 56.78d,
                p_bl = true,
                p_dt = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1),
                p_m = 90.12m,
                p_b1 = 12,
                p_b2 = -34,
                p_c = 'c',
                p_s1 = -21,
                p_s2 = 43,
                p_ts = new TimeSpan(12, 34, 56),
                p_id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                p_uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com"),
                p_ba = new[] { (byte)1, (byte)3, (byte)2 },
                p_t = typeof(ClassTwo),
                p_sa = new[] { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" },
                p_ia = new[] { 7, 4, 9 },
                p_e1 = EnumOne.Three,
                p_e2 = EnumTwo.One | EnumTwo.Two,
                p_list = new List<ClassFive>(new[]
                {
                    new ClassFive()
                    {
                        i = 1,
                        s = "1"
                    },
                    new ClassFive()
                    {
                        i = 2,
                        s = "2"
                    }
                }),
                // fields
                f_i1 = -123,
                f_i2 = 456,
                f_l1 = -456,
                f_l2 = 123,
                f_s = "str",
                f_f = 12.34f,
                f_d = 56.78d,
                f_bl = true,
                f_dt = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1),
                f_m = 90.12m,
                f_b1 = 12,
                f_b2 = -34,
                f_c = 'c',
                f_s1 = -21,
                f_s2 = 43,
                f_ts = new TimeSpan(12, 34, 56),
                f_id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                f_uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com"),
                f_ba = new[] { (byte)1, (byte)3, (byte)2 },
                f_t = typeof(ClassTwo),
                f_sa = new[] { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" },
                f_ia = new[] { 7, 4, 9 },
                f_e1 = EnumOne.Three,
                f_e2 = EnumTwo.One | EnumTwo.Two,
                f_list = new List<ClassFive>(new[]
                {
                    new ClassFive()
                    {
                        i = 1,
                        s = "1"
                    },
                    new ClassFive()
                    {
                        i = 2,
                        s = "2"
                    }
                })
            };
            var classThree = new ClassThree()
            {
                ss = "333",
                one = classOne,
                two = classOne
            };
            return classThree;
        }
    }

    public enum EnumOne
    {
        One = 1,
        Two = 2,
        Three = 3
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum EnumTwo
    {
        One = 1,
        Two = 2,
        Three = 4
    }

    [ProtoContract, ProtoInclude(51, typeof(ClassSix))]
    public class ClassOne
    {
        // properties

        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public int p_i1 { set; get; }

        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public uint p_i2 { set; get; }

        [ProtoMember(3)]
        public long p_l1 { set; get; }

        [ProtoMember(4)]
        public ulong p_l2 { set; get; }

        [ProtoMember(5)]
        public string p_s { set; get; }

        [ProtoMember(6)]
        public float p_f { set; get; }

        [ProtoMember(7)]
        public double p_d { set; get; }

        [ProtoMember(8)]
        public bool p_bl { set; get; }

        [ProtoMember(9)]
        public DateTime p_dt { set; get; }

        [ProtoMember(10)]
        public decimal p_m { set; get; }

        [ProtoMember(11)]
        public byte p_b1 { set; get; }

        [ProtoMember(12)]
        public sbyte p_b2 { set; get; }

        [ProtoMember(13)]
        public char p_c { set; get; }

        [ProtoMember(14)]
        public short p_s1 { set; get; }

        [ProtoMember(15)]
        public ushort p_s2 { set; get; }

        [ProtoMember(16)]
        public TimeSpan p_ts { set; get; }

        [ProtoMember(17)]
        public Guid p_id { set; get; }

        [ProtoMember(18)]
        public Uri p_uri { set; get; }

        [ProtoMember(19)]
        public byte[] p_ba { set; get; }

        [ProtoMember(20)]
        public Type p_t { set; get; }

        [ProtoMember(21)]
        public string[] p_sa { set; get; }

        [ProtoMember(22)]
        public int[] p_ia { set; get; }

        [ProtoMember(23)]
        public EnumOne p_e1 { set; get; }

        [ProtoMember(24)]
        public EnumTwo p_e2 { set; get; }

        [ProtoMember(25)]
        public List<ClassFive> p_list { set; get; }

        // fields

        [ProtoMember(26)]
        public int f_i1 = 0;

        [ProtoMember(27)]
        public uint f_i2 = 0;

        [ProtoMember(28)]
        public long f_l1 = 0L;

        [ProtoMember(29)]
        public ulong f_l2 = 0UL;

        [ProtoMember(30)]
        public string f_s = string.Empty;

        [ProtoMember(31)]
        public float f_f = 0f;

        [ProtoMember(32)]
        public double f_d = 0d;

        [ProtoMember(33)]
        public bool f_bl = false;

        [ProtoMember(34)]
        public DateTime f_dt = DateTime.MinValue;

        [ProtoMember(35)]
        public decimal f_m = 0m;

        [ProtoMember(36)]
        public byte f_b1 = 0;

        [ProtoMember(37)]
        public sbyte f_b2 = 0;

        [ProtoMember(38)]
        public char f_c = (char)0;

        [ProtoMember(39)]
        public short f_s1 = 0;

        [ProtoMember(40)]
        public ushort f_s2 = 0;

        [ProtoMember(41)]
        public TimeSpan f_ts = TimeSpan.Zero;

        [ProtoMember(42)]
        public Guid f_id = Guid.Empty;

        [ProtoMember(43)]
        public Uri f_uri = null;

        [ProtoMember(44)]
        public byte[] f_ba = null;

        [ProtoMember(45)]
        public Type f_t = null;

        [ProtoMember(46)]
        public string[] f_sa = null;

        [ProtoMember(47)]
        public int[] f_ia = null;

        [ProtoMember(48)]
        public EnumOne f_e1 = 0;

        [ProtoMember(49)]
        public EnumTwo f_e2 = 0;

        [ProtoMember(50)]
        public List<ClassFive> f_list = null;
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public class ClassSix : ClassOne
    {

    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public class ClassTwo
    {
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public interface IClass
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        string ss
        {
            set;
            get;
        }
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        ClassOne one
        {
            set;
            get;
        }
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public class ClassThree : IClass
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string ss { set; get; }

        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public ClassOne one { set; get; }

        [ProtoMember(3)]
        public ClassSix two { set; get; }
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public class ClassFour
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string ss { set; get; }

        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public ClassOne one { set; get; }
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public class ClassFive
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public int i { set; get; }

        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public string s { set; get; }
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW I ran about 5000 cycles of your code on .Net 4.0 / PBuf v 2.0.0.640 without issue :-(

Comment: Yes, it happens randomly. Once I run it for over 2 hours without any problem. Yet in another instance I got the exception after a few thousand cycles.

Comment: I will investigate - can't do much right now (https://mobile.twitter.com/marcgravell/status/375875031538348032/photo/1?screen_name=marcgravell)

Comment: BTW - the latest build includes some object pooling - the first place I'll look is a thread race there...

Comment: Following the comment from @MarcGravell, I tried to use Parallel.For instead of for loop, and the error happens more frequently.

Comment: For info, I'm having great difficulty getting this to repro... it just... *works* - at least in my tests (using `Parallel.For`). What sort of cycle count are you seeing this at?

Comment: Just updated the code to rev 666, and the latest error is at 11129. FYI, I'm using release build config with *FEAT_COMPILER FEAT_SERVICEMODEL PLAT_BINARYFORMATTER PLAT_XMLSERIALIZER* enabled. This is tested in Win 7 x64, *but*, it's running in Parallels Desktop (don't know if this relevant or not). And I'm also running older version (rev. 658), and so far no error (at the time I'm writing this, the code has been running for over 37k+).

Comment: I've just noticed the same error in my logs which brought me to this question. My program is reading from a message queue and if an error occurs (such as this) it rolls back the transaction and retries. In other words, it tries to deserialize the same message again and when it does it usually succeeds (which reinforces this being an intermittent issue). I'm using version 2.0.0.666.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated to rev. 669 and so far haven't encounter the error again. So I'm reporting this as fixed for now.

---

Comment: I think r668 fixed this, but yes: a bug was found

Comment: The latest version I see is r668. Where can I find r669 please?

Comment: I only see r668 is there an r669?